# unable to restore Tensorflow checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to restore saved checkpoint in Tensorflow. The model is available in [this](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz) link. However, I am unable to find any restores variables. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have tried the following code.

```py
PATH_REL_META = r'./model.ckpt.meta'

# start tensorflow session
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # import graph
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(PATH_REL_META)

    # load weights for graph
    saver.restore(sess, PATH_REL_META[:-5])

    # get all global variables (including model variables)
    vars_global = tf.global_variables()

    # get their name and value and put them into dictionary
    sess.as_default()
    model_vars = {}
    for var in vars_global:
        try:
            model_vars[var.name] = var.eval()
        except:
            print("For var={}, an exception occurred".format(var.name))
    print (model_vars)
```

***model_vars*** variable is just an empty array when I print it. Why am I not able to restore the checkpoint properly?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting checkpoint file? What's the output of `tf.train.list_variables(file.ckpt)`?

Comment: You are right! `list_variables` seems to give all variables. But why is `tf.global_variables()` giving an empty list?

Comment: try `tf.get_default_graph().get_all_collection_keys()`, from there get `tf.get_collection(collection_key)`

Comment: Collection keys is empty. `tf.get_default_graph()` gives me access to the graph loaded in gpu?

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with checkpoint. Your code should work